# How to add percentage sign and pp into a asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagrid

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and developing in Visual Basic. I have a gridview in a web form and I need for some cell to show 
- % beside the number
- pp (percentage point) beside the number
- just a number

This varies between columns and rows like for example:

```
KPI             2012   2013    var
Volume          18     20      11%
VolumeToRevenue 10%    15%     5pp
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The entity ref for % percent symbol is

```
"&#37;" which displays in html as...
```

%

Comment: I've resolved the problem by creating a datatable and adding adding % and pp(percentage points) when needed. The problem is that you can not change the data type in datables, so I had to add new columns and format them as string beforehand. Afterwards I deleted the columns that I didn't need. Finally, I've loaded the data in the datagrid by datagrid.datasource = datatabe datagrid.databind().  Hope this helps someone

Comment: Hello Selrac, Hmmm will that not affect your data elsewhere? The reason I ask is because you cannot perform numeric mathematical functions on strings. And if you need the numeric data elsewhere or need to perform calculations on it then it wont be straight forward and you may need to convert the string back to numeric format.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't think I'll need the data later on, but Yes, I realise it would be a problem. At the moment I'm calculating it beforehand like: dt.Rows(i)(10) = (dt.Rows(i)(1) - dt.Rows(i)(2)) & "pp"

Answer (score 0):

Use [`BoundField.DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) Property:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" 
                HeaderText="ProductID" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="ProductID" 
                DataFormatString="{0:D6}" />
```

Change `DataFormatString` to one of following:

```
{0}%               // number + %
{0}pp              // number + pp
{0}                // just a number
```

Comment: Thanks, but this formats the whole column. I need the first row with no-format, no-format, % and the second row as %, %, pp